# ¿Como puedo hacer que SASS no salte con el "output" cada vez que algo está mal en mi código?

Tags: css, vscode, sass, scss

A menudo minimizo VS Code con el código a medias y el Live SASS Compiler me saca el output cada vez que vuelvo a maximizar la ventana. ¿Alguien sabe arreglar esto? Gracias.
Imagen del error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la configuración del módulo puedes encontrar la solución. Te muestro aquí las posibles configuraciones: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md Es posible que está última sea lo que estás buscando liveSassCompile.settings.showOutputWindow

Comment: Correcto, justo lo que buscaba, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

[image: live sass compilar settings]

Buenas, buscando la solución a este problema llegué a este posteo. Luego de probar la edición del archivo json encontré esta configuración en las settings de la extension en vscode. Lo comparto por si alguien mas lo necesita.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] y describe el contenido de la imagen, ya que [no todos podrán verla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).